# Using magic constants to access object properties

Tags: php, magic-constants, object-notation

I am about to load a language object as a property from controller object like this:

```
$this->lang = new Languages(en)
```

Inside the methods of my controller object i am currently accessing the specific translation like this:

```
function = myFunction(){

$magic = __FUNCTION__;
$lang = $this->lang->$magic;

~~ mycode

}
```

BUT i want something like this to make it "leaner" code:

```
$lang = $this->lang->__FUNCTION__;
```

Does anybody know how to use the Magic Constants in object notation properly ?
Unfortunately i havent found any answer here or official php.net website

Comment: `$lang = $this->lang->{__FUNCTION__}();` maybe? Or if you really wanted a property `$lang = $this->lang->{__FUNCTION__};` Never tested.

Comment: `$this->lang->{__FUNCTION__}` did work ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @AbraCadaver suggested, `$this->lang->{__FUNCTION__}` is working